# how can I print the array in reverse order using while loop? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to print out the array in reverse order without using the reverse(). The output of my code just printed 13. Is there something missing in my code? Still new to python so I'm stumbling about just to figure out how things works.

This is my code:

```
arr = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]

def oddNumberReverse(arr):
   i = len(arr) - 1
   while i < len(arr):
       if arr[i] % 2 == 1:
           print (arr[i])
       i += 1
       return (arr)

oddNumberReverse(arr)
```

The output should be the full array in reverse order but my output is 13.

Comment: Well, you `return` as part of the loop, which will end the entire function.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat if he want to use `while` he should probably use `pop()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few problems in your attempt:

1.Keep the `return` outside the while loop

2.Take an empty list `lst` to append values

3.`while` should go greater than `0`

4.`append` values `arr([i])` to `lst`

```
arr = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]

def oddNumberReverse(arr):
   i = len(arr) - 1
   lst = []
   while i > 0:
       if arr[i] % 2 == 1:
           lst.append(arr[i])
       i -= 1
   return lst

oddNumberReverse(arr)

#output
[13, 11, 9, 7, 5, 3]
```

Comment: Keep in mind that [returning is not printing](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/#returning-vs-printing:~:text=Since%20you%E2%80%99re%20still%20learning%20the%20difference%20between%20returning%20and%20printing%20a%20value%2C%20you%20might%20expect%20your%20script%20to%20print%204%20to%20the%20screen.%20However%2C%20that%E2%80%99s%20not%20what%20happens%2C%20and%20you%20get%20nothing%20on%20your%20screen.), even if sometimes it does print the returned value. If you ran this code as `python code.py` you would get no output.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues in your code

1. `return` at the level of while loop terminates the function after 1 iteration
2. loop counter is incorrect

Try going backwards -

```
arr = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]

def oddNumberReverse(arr):
   i = len(arr) - 1
   while i >= 0:
       if arr[i] % 2 == 1:
           print (arr[i])
       i -= 1
   return arr

oddNumberReverse(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```py
arr = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]

while len(arr) > 0 and (num := arr.pop(-1)) is not None:
    print(num)
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to make the while shorter.

`while (num := arr.pop(-1)) is not None:` whill raise `IndexError` because `pop` will fail when the last element has been taken.

### Update:

Sure can be shorter :D

```py
arr = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]

while arr:
    print(arr.pop(-1))
```

If arr is not empty it is considered Truthy, running the code inside the while.
If arr is empty it is considered Falsey, not running the code inside the while and avoiding an `IndexError`.

[Other truth/false value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing:%7E:text=constants%20defined%20to,%2C%20range(0)) from the official docs.